# EventListener nao funciona com 2 ou mais inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Então amigos, eu tenho uma pagina com um for que faz criar varios formularios. Em cada form eu tenho um input file, que eu quero tratar individualmente.
Porem, quando eu tento usar algum eventlistener, ele só funciona com o primeiro input do for. Eu não sei como posso fazer para todos funcionarem.
Eu fiz um JSFiddle ilustrando o meu problema aqui. Notem que o alert só é acionado no primeiro caso, já nos demais nada acontece.

Alguem tem alguma solução?

**EDIT**
link do fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2wapy6uo/

Comment: Acho que o seu fiddle não veio...

Comment: #CadeOFiddle? haha

Comment: pronto haha, tanto projeto que a cabeça nao aguenta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar `querySelectorAll` e usar um `each` para cada um dos elementos, como no abaixo:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.sliderAluno');

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    input.onchange= function()
    {
        alert("event");
    }
});
```

Comment: não funcionou aqui.

Comment: atualizei a resposta, olha agora

Comment: Deu certinho, valeu!!!